# Windows form UI freezing and unable to execute user action when too much data is coming in

Tags: c#, serial-port

Created a simple window form to receive and process data from serial port
also logging the data in textfile and displaying in the rich-text box.

For some reason, it is going into unresponsive state and not able to execute user action and freeze.

According to my understanding, earlier code was using two threads one UI and another one for data received event. Is this correct

But now as i am using background worker, it should create anther thread to process and append in the log and richtext box. Is this correct?

This is my first project in c# so pardon me if it is already answered somewhere else as i am unable to correlate this situation with the given answers and not able to implement them.

Is it a good idea to background worker if not then how can i solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Earlier the entire application was running on UI thread. Now i have tried to use background to create a new thread to store data receiving from serial port and processing inside that thread

```
//earlier code
void DataReceived_Event(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Port.IsOpen)
    {
        int bytes = Port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        Port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        receivedBytes.AddRange(buffer);
        ProcessRecievedBytes(null);
    }
}

//latest code with background worker
void DataReceived_Event(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Port.IsOpen)
    {
        int bytes = Port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];

        Port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        receivingBytes.AddRange(buffer);

        if (!essentialBgWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            receivedBytes.AddRange(receivingBytes);
            receivingBytes.Clear();
            essentialBgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
 }

private void essentialBgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (byte hexByte in receivedBytes)
    {
        //color = Color.Gray;
        if ((Config.Data.Serial_DisplayLevel == GLOBAL.HEX_LEVEL_NONE))
        {
            if ((hexByte == '\n') || ((hexByte >= 0x20) && (hexByte <= 0x7E)))
            {
                String tmpString = new String((char)hexByte, 1);
                //essentialBgWorker.ReportProgress(0, tmpString);
                //in here i am putting in the log file and appending in the richtext box
                PreprocessAppend(tmpString, Color.Black, false);
            }
        }
    }

    process.ProcessData(receivedBytes);//in here i am processing the data
    receivedBytes.Clear();
}


private void essentialBgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string str = e.UserState.ToString();
    logWriter.Write(str);
    logWriter.Flush();

    if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
    {
        AppendSerial(str, Color.Black, false);
    }
    else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 1)
    {
        AppendSerial(str, Color.Black, false);
    }
}


SerialTab.SerialPort.AppendSerial += delegate (string data, Color txtColor, bool newLineCheck)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate ()
    {
        if (newLineCheck && (serialTextBox.Text != "") && (serialTextBox.Text[serialTextBox.TextLength - 1] != '\r') && (serialTextBox.Text[serialTextBox.TextLength - 1] != '\n'))
        {
            data = "\n" + data;
        }

        AppendTextbox(serialTextBox, data, txtColor);
    }));
};

void AppendTextbox(RichTextBox tb, string data, Color txtColor)
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    int start = tb.TextLength;
    tb.AppendText(data);
    int end = tb.TextLength;

    // Textbox may transform chars, so (end-start) != text.Length
    tb.Select(start, end - start);
    tb.SelectionColor = txtColor;

    //reset color to defaults
    tb.SelectionLength = 0;
    tb.SelectionColor = serialTextBox.ForeColor;

    //move caret to bottom of page
    ScrollToBottom(tb);

    //ensure text buffer stays below 15000 characters
    checkTextBoxLength(tb);
}

void checkTextBoxLength(RichTextBox box)
{
    //ensure text buffer in text box gets too large
    if (box.Text.Length > 15000)
    {
        box.ReadOnly = false;
        box.SelectionStart = 0;
        box.SelectionLength = box.TextLength - 10000;
        box.SelectedText = "";
        box.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The DataReceived event happens on a secondary thread already, it won’t block the UI thread unless you do something wrong. Are you poking at the UI from there? Where exactly does it hang when you debug it?

Comment: i am using Port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes); to read the bytes from UART and every time it receives it checks whether it "end of line", "ascii" or not and then it put in rich text box and then log it and then process it at the end

Comment: And which exact part hangs?

Comment: even though i am running it in debug mode but for some reason i am unable to do anything on ui. I have few more text box to send commands which i cant even select also there is a menutip and that is also not working. It is not even throwing any error so how can i debug to see where is the problem

Comment: When it hangs in debug mode select Break all from Visual Studio’s Debug menu and see where it is. If it doesn’t show the place check different threads from the drop down. Or put a breakpoint inside the receive and step line by line through.

Comment: i tried putting break all and it showed that it was in tb.AppendText(data); part of "append text box" and one time it came on checkTextBoxLength part of "append text box" does that mean that this is taking too much time or something else

Comment: And was it in UI thread or not? If not, that’s the problem. You need to invoke into UI thread to do anything to the UI

Answer (score 0):

Don't access windows controls from any thread other than the one that created them. When using a BackgroundWorker:

- add the backgroundworker to the form designer
- set its ReportsProgress property to true
- attach an event handler to DoWork and another to ProgressChanged
- in the DoWork event, do your background work such as reading from the serial port. Any time you want to update a windows control, call the backgroundworker ReportProgress() method with an object argument for the user state that contains some data you want to use in the control
- I tend to use the progress int to also specify something, such as running a switch statement to chose one of several text boxes to update

The background worker will correctly ensure the ProgressChanged event is executed by the UI thread, meaning you can update controls from within it

Looking at your code, it seems you were going along these lines because I can see a commented out ReportProgress call. Show the contents of your ProgressChanged event handler. Make absolutely sure the only time you ever access any windows control (read or write any property or call any method) is in ProgressChanged, NOT DoWork

---

Edit/Update

Now I can see more of your code, it looks like you've embarked on a path of making it all way too complicated. I'll make another answer

Comment: I have updated my question with the reportprogress method but could i see was that it was getting called multiple times and putting the data in correct order

Comment: What does AppendSerial do? It's hard to help you because you're not posting all the code. To keep a windows application responsive a) don't access windows controls from threads other Jan the one that created hem and b) don't do long or blocking operations on the UI thread. ProgressChanged handler should ONLY be used to put data into your UI controls and it should complete quickly. If you have any data conversion etc to do, do it in DoWork before you send it to be displayed in the UI via ReportProgress/ProgressChanged

Comment: I have updated my question with the append serial method.

Comment: Theoretically, it makes sense that i should not call controls other than UI thread. This is what i tried to do with report progress thread but i could see that that report progress was getting called multiple times and it is not synchronized with do work

Comment: Only you call ReportProgress(), so it must be synced with DoWork

Comment: Edit/Update:

You're making this way too complicated, having an event from the serial port and starting a backgroundworker every time data is received - it's not necessary. Then you've tacked on Invokation because you were trying to access the form controls from the bgw's worker thread not the ui thread.. I recommend you go back to the earlier code, where you just respond to a DataReceived event, on the UI thread and let that be the end of it. Don't perform any long operations on that thread (it looks like you're just getting the data and pushing it into a textbox - it should be a few ms)

Comment: could you pass some basic code because i have tried the way you mention in your answer but still it didnt work

Comment: In this answer or my other answer ? I recommend the other answer

Comment: the other answer you are referring to is "I recommend you junk all of your existing code". Can you please show me how would i raise an event on ui thread to know that i have to do process the data and how would i put into the control and also where would i use logWriter to log the data into the text file

Comment: BackgroundWorker exists to run long running CPU bound operations in a background thread.  It doesn't exist to manage asynchronous IO.  It's features simply aren't suited to the task.

Comment: @CaiusJard can you please explain what you meant by "made an edit to that answer "

Comment: It means “since your comment has been posted the answer has had an edit applied”. I said “that answer” rather than “this answer” because I mean the other answer I made, not the one this comment is posted under

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you junk all of your existing code, and proceed with using something like this, derived from [the example from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();


        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

            textBox1.InvokeIfRequired(ctrl => ctrl.AppendText(indata));
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort.Close();
        }

    }

    public static class ControlHelpers
    {
        public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T control, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control.Invoke(new Action(() => action(control)), null);
            }
            else
            {
                action(control);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your DataReceived handler is quite complex. The MSDN example uses a far simpler interface where it takes care internally of the reading and buffering etc with ReadExisting. You might want to attach to it and just keep appending the data you received into some kind of buffer (stringbuilder?), and regularly inspect the buffer to see if it contains a full message that you want to process

Comment: Console.WriteLine is thread-safe, so from the questioners PoV this is cheating .

Comment: Not if he junks the existing handler/bgw code and uses the DataReceived event (executed by UI thread) to sp.ReadExisting and push that data into a UI control? The problems didn't start when multithreading via bgw were introduced, but they weren't solved by it either- it would be best to remove it again

Comment: The `DataReceived` event is on it's own thread!  He'll either have to Invoke to update the UI or call his backgroundworker report progress to update the UI.

Comment: @CaiusJard would you be able to explain how class "ControlHelper'  in your answer is different from my code in "AppendSerial" method and how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do and you kind of have the right idea, I think you are just having a threading issue.  Do you have the code for your `PreprocessAppend` method?  You probably need to use `BeginInvoke` in that function and that should fix your issue.

Personally, I don't think you need a backgroundworker, as the Serial `DataReceived` event is threaded.  I would recommend what the other answer said and use `ReadExisting` as that will grab all the characters in the received buffer and you can determine what to do from there.  Just be careful because the `DataReceived` event can fire whenever it determines is a good time, so you could only get a partial line back.  If you go this route you'll have to build your string until you know you have the whole thing and then process it.

In my example below, I'm expecting a Line Feed as my terminator so I build a string until I have the whole line then I process it.

```
//private variables
private SerialPort sp;
private StringBuilder sb;
private char LF = (char)10;

//function to initialize all my objects
public void init_state_machine()
{
    sp = new SerialPort(currentSettings.ComPort, currentSettings.BaudRate);
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Clear();
}

private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string currentLine = "";
    string Data = sp.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            //because it's threaded its possible to enter this code while processing so we will
            //clear our string building immediately
            currentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            //process your line here or whatever
            processReceivedData(currentLine);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}

//this is where you process the response.  For a simple example I just append the string
//to our textbox, but you could do any computations in here.
private void processReceivedData(string s)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
    {
        serialTextBox.Text += s;
    });
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i am doing but instead of "ReadExisting" method, i am using  "Port.Read"method. It is working when there is no too much data coming in continuously and UI is responsive as well. The problem starts when too much data continuously coming on serial and i can see that "richtext" box is refreshing to show the latest data but the moment when i try to send couple of commands or do something else on UI, everything freeze and "non responsive" text gets appended to the form name and then after sometime, It goes away when it stops getting too much data on serial port

Comment: i have put break all when it froze and it shows me the break point in appendtextbox method and looked at threads                                              

Not Flagged > 12280 10 Main Thread Main Thread "System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc"

I dont know what is this? Can anyone please explain why it is getting stuck and richtextbox is still refreshing to show me the latest data but UI is not responding

Comment: You should wrap you whole appendtextbox method with your `this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate ()`.  You begin invoke it before you call it but maybe there is a place you are calling appendtextbox and not invoking it.  It would be better to invoke it in the function instead of outside of the function.  You should also do `if(this.InvokeRequired)` and only invoke updating the gui if it's required.